# Como identificar o erro no código PHP pelo Chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome

Eu escrevo meu código no Sublime e quando tento executar a tela do chrome fica em branco. Como uma virgula pode causar um monte de problemas, fico relendo e relendo código à procura de erros.
Porque o meu Chrome não indica os erros?

Comment: Não seria porque php é lido e interpretado pelo **servidor php** e não pelo navegador? Diferente de javascript e de html, PHP não vai pro navegador.

Comment: Você pode instalar esse plugin no Sublime, http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/, ele identifica erros como falta de `;` ou fechamento de chaves, pra você não precisar procurar por isso no código.

Comment: Entendi. Apesar disso, estou acompanhando as aulas do Curso em Video, e no caso dele, o navegador sempre informa os erros, igual ao javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Coloque no início do seu código:

```
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

e caso tenha o error_reporting(0), comente:

```
//error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Incluí os métodos ao meu código e agora, de fato, o navegador indica alguma coisa ao invés de uma página em branco. Porém preciso de ajuda para entender qual o problema. Vou colar aqui os erros indicados:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private carro::__construct() from invalid context in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/POO - PHP/Teste/index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/POO - PHP/Teste/index.php on line 15

Comment: me indica uma fonte para eu entender melhor esses métodos.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesses vídeos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPs8o9v3gVkIYfO1jlbb5jA

Comment: Sobre o erro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997721/fatal-error-call-to-private-myobject-construct-from-invalid-context

Comment: Em continuidade dos meus estudos, encontrei uma forma mais simples de identificar os erros do código PHP. Localize o arquivo php.ini e busque a linha 'display_errors = off'e altere para 'display_errors = on'. Pronto! Com isso os erros aparecerão naturalmente assim que o HTML for carregado.

Answer (score 1):

O PHP é interpretado pelo servidor web (apache, nginx) e sua resposta é entregue a quem o chamou (navegador, ajax). Para visualizar eventuais erros que possam acontecer você deve habilitar a exibição de erros do PHP, no arquivo `php.ini` existe uma diretiva chamada `display_errors` mude o valor dela para `1` ou `On`. Assim quando acontecerem erros os mesmo serão exibidos na tela.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque essas duas linhas no início do seu código que fará com que o PHP reporte e mostre **TODOS** os erros e avisos:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // mesmo resultado de: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Caso queira que todo seu ambiente exiba tais erros e avisos, altere estas mesmas diretivas na configuração do PHP (arquivo `php.ini`) e **reinicie o servidor HTTP** (Apache/IIS/Nginx/etc).

Exemplo de configuração do `error_reporting`:

[image: Print php.ini]

Obs.: as linhas iniciadas por ponto e vírgula `;` são comentários. A configuração se dá pela linha:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

As opções estão disponíveis na documentação.

> Mais detalhes, vide documentação:
>
> [PHP: error_reporting](http://error_reporting)
>
> [PHP: display_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)
>
> [PHP: ini_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)