# Não aparece erro em PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um código bem simples em PHP e inserindo um erro de propósito, quando atualizo meu browser o resultado que me aparece é apenas uma página em branco, gostaria que aparecesse um erro com a causa e a linha do erro.

obs: uso ubuntu 18.04

Comment: opa, é bom postar o código para podermos entender melhor

Comment: Possível duplicata: [Como identificar o erro no código PHP pelo Chrome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272788/como-identificar-o-erro-no-c%C3%B3digo-php-pelo-chrome) (já que esta foi fechada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque essas duas linhas no início do seu código que fará com que o PHP reporte e mostre **TODOS** os erros e avisos:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // mesmo resultado de: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Caso queira que todo seu ambiente exiba tais erros e avisos, altere estas mesmas diretivas na configuração do PHP (arquivo `php.ini`) e **reinicie o servidor HTTP** (Apache/IIS/Nginx/etc).

Exemplo de configuração do `error_reporting`:

[image: Print php.ini]

Obs.: as linhas iniciadas por ponto e vírgula `;` são comentários. A configuração se dá pela linha:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

As opções estão disponíveis na documentação.

> Mais detalhes, vide documentação:
>
> [PHP: error_reporting](http://error_reporting)
>
> [PHP: display_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)
>
> [PHP: ini_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: O display error apenas a variável Production Value está como 'off' e em error_reporting as variáveis possuem os seguintes valores: ; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Comment: @zeka04 preciso te dizer que as linhas iniciadas por `;` são apenas comentários ou vc já sabe? kk

Comment: então tudo isso é comentário e não config do meu php? desculpa sou iniciante

Comment: @zeka04 resposta atualizada, bro

Comment: acho que agora vai, então eu só preciso mudar essa linha que você indiciou por error_reporting = E_ALL? Porque ela já está com o valor que está no seu print

Comment: @zeka04 então, cara. O ideal é você configurar conforme SUA necessidade. `E_ALL` **reporta** tudo. Mas você ainda precisa conferir a diretiva `display_errors`. Senão os erros não serão exibidos no navegador. Só nos logs.

Comment: eu mudei a diretiva display_errors para ON e ainda não funciona... caramba que loucura

Comment: @zeka04 Reiniciou o servidor Apache/Nginx?

Comment: caramba faltava isso, muito obrigado pela paciência e atenção.