# PDO funciona no localhost, mas não no webservice

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Fiz uma aplicação e ela roda no `localhost` sem problema algum. Quando passei pra hospedagem ele simplesmente não lê os comandos SQL pelo PDO (está habilitado no `php.ini`).

A conexão parece funcionar numa boa, não reporta erros.

```
<?php  
   try {
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx.xx;dbname=xxxxx', "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Mas quando eu tento uma busca com SQL e PDO não aparece nada:

```
<?PHP
include ("conexao.php");

$login = $_POST["login"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$usuario = 0;

echo "Teste 1"; 

$query = $pdo ->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login = :login AND senha = :senha");
$query->bindValue(":login", $login);
$query->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
$query->execute();
$linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$aux = $query->rowCount();

  echo "Teste 2";
  // (resto do código, mas não chega nessas parte, testei com echo)
```

edit: apaguei o php.ini e deixei rodar o da própria hospedagem, tá funcionando agora

Comment: O php está rodando na mesma hospedagem do banco de dados? Retorna algum erro? Seu PHP tá configurado pra exibir os erros? - Se está acessando o banco de dados externamente, o usuário tem permissão para acesso externo?

Comment: "*- não reporta erros*" Já achei um erro: `$conn = new PDO('...` e depois vc usa `$query = $pdo ->prepare("...`. Tá errado! Não era pra funcionar nem no seu `localhost`. Estranho, heim! 

Comment: @LipESprY esse erro foi meu ao publicar aqui, as variáveis são as mesmas, tava fazendo vários testes pra tentar encontrar o erro. Respondendo as perguntas, os arquivos php e o banco estão na mesma hospedagem. Nenhum erro é retornado. Atribuí total permissão pro usuário.

Comment: Seu PHP tá [configurado pra exibir os erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370002/n%C3%A3o-aparece-erro-em-php/370004#370004)? Por se tratar de hospedagem, vem configurado para não exibir por padrão (produção).

Comment: não está configurado pra isso, aliás, nem sei como faz pra exibir erros do php em um webservice

Comment: Abre esse link aí que tem o `ini_set` que pode habilitar ao rodar o script...

Comment: apaguei o php.ini e deixei utilizando o do da hospedagem e tá funcionando pelo que parece

Comment: Como assim?! Ohxi! Isso não tem cabimento! Kkkk

Comment: não tenho ideia do porquê, mas se funcionou vou deixar, espero que não cause problemas maiores depois. mas a própria hostgator recomenda usar o deles, testei e deu certo