# Problema no redirect das páginas Editar e Excluir no PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tudo bem pessoal, estou com um problema esquisito, desenvolvi um sistema de cadastro simples de agenda.

repositorio git: https://github.com/guischpor/sistemacadastrophp

Fiz o deploy do projeto no meu site de hospedagem na hostinger:
http://syscadastro.guiportela.tech/index.php

O projeto roda e funciona normalmente no servidor local, ele adiciona um novo registro, deleta e alterar qualquer valor e realiza a consulta.

No servidor da hostinger onde upei o site, ele realiza a consulta e add novos registros, o problema e quando clico no botão de alterar e excluir, ele da erro.
Já tentei tudo o que eu podia, gostaria de alguma ajuda.

Os arquivos de manipulação do db esta na pasta banco_de_dados, o link do repositorio está acima.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia e me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem mais de um problema pelo que vi, mas os que citou, ocorrem devido ao link gerado. Teu sistema está gerando o link de editar assim:

http://syscadastro.guiportela.tech/editar.php%20?%20id=2

E deveria ser:

http://syscadastro.guiportela.tech/editar.php?id=2

Se trocar o %20?%20 por ? funciona.
Porém, não salvou e nem excluiu.
Mas o erro original é por causa do link mesmo.
Uma dica é ativar as mensagens de erro do PHP no modo desenvolvimento.
Mais informações aqui: [Como identificar o erro no código PHP pelo Chrome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272788/como-identificar-o-erro-no-c%C3%B3digo-php-pelo-chrome)
Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, é o que eu estava pensando, vou dar uma olhada no conteúdo que você me enviou, qualquer dúvida eu retorno, respondendo se consegui ou não.

Comment: Iniciei e visualizei com mais atenção no código. 
Tinha uns espaços que eu tinha deixado para melhor visualização no meu código, eliminei esses espaços no arquivo read.php

Consegui, e funcionou tanto para editar e excluir, você me ajudou muito.

Falta agora arrumar algumas pequenas coisas, fora isso, agradeço novamente.

Comment: Tamos ai, @GuiScholzPortela